# I want to implement TinyMCE in my Wordpress plugin. HOW?

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

Basically need the default Wordpress `TinyMCE` WYSIWYG editor where the user will enter some formatted text in my plugin. How do I integrate/implement `TinyMCE` in a simple HTML Wordpress form??

I'm using Wordpress v2.9!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855890/add-tinymce-to-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is `wp_tiny_mce`. Here is how to include the editor in one of your plugin’s admin panel.

1. Include this code in the `admin_head` hook

   ```
   add_filter('admin_head','zd_multilang_tinymce');

   function zd_multilang_tinymce() {
       wp_admin_css('thickbox');
       wp_print_scripts('jquery-ui-core');
       wp_print_scripts('jquery-ui-tabs');
       wp_print_scripts('post');
       wp_print_scripts('editor');
       add_thickbox();
       wp_print_scripts('media-upload');
       if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) wp_tiny_mce();
       // use the if condition because this function doesn't exist in version prior to 2.7
   }
   ```
2. Call the editor anywhere you need it to be displayed

   ```
   the_editor($content_to_load);
   ```

[Source](http://blog.zen-dreams.com/en/2008/11/06/how-to-include-tinymce-in-your-wp-plugin/)