# Wordpress content editor - TinyMCE php file not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I built a very basic little site for my cousin's bakery. I made a Divi Child theme and added only three very basic plugins - Yoast, Photo Gallery and Password-protected.

After migrating from localhost, I noticed that the content editors are not working - neither visual nor text, neither regular nor in Divi-builder. The attached image is the console showing the TinyMCE issues.

I had trying deactivating all plugins, changing theme, reuploading Divi, reuploading TinyMCE, and I don't know what else to do. It works perfectly fine on localhost.

If one of you was willing to take a closer look, I'd give access, because I don't know what else to do.

[Here's the image of the console with the wp-tinemce issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INzjH.png)

**EDIT**: Contents of my wp-tinemce.php file - basic, unedited since the installation:

**wp-tinymce.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Disable error reporting
 *
 * Set this to error_reporting( -1 ) for debugging.
 */
error_reporting(0);

$basepath = dirname(__FILE__);

function get_file($path) {

if ( function_exists('realpath') )
    $path = realpath($path);

if ( ! $path || ! @is_file($path) )
    return false;

return @file_get_contents($path);
}

$expires_offset = 31536000; // 1 year

header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding'); // Handle proxies
header('Expires: ' . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $expires_offset ) .     ' GMT');
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=$expires_offset");

if ( isset($_GET['c']) && 1 == $_GET['c'] &&      isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])
    && false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') && (     $file = get_file($basepath . '/wp-tinymce.js.gz') ) ) {

    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    echo $file;
} else {
    // Back compat. This file shouldn't be used if this condition can occur     (as in, if gzip isn't accepted).
    echo get_file( $basepath . '/tinymce.min.js' );
    echo get_file( $basepath . '/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js' );
}
exit;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this issue? Perhaps post the contents of your `wp-tinymce.php` and `post.php` scripts which are giving you the first couple of errors...?

Comment: Also, I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808337/4814251) answer would help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey - neither of those files have been editted at all since the wordpress installation, but I posted the contents. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: First, you're trying to access your `.js` scripts locally and not include them using [HTML `script` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp). Second, why are you silencing errors from your `file_get_contents` function? Try using [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for error handling instead of avoiding them altogether. Try that and see what errors occur on your deployment server.